# css Hover li tag select inside first ul only not in select inside ul

Tags: css

CSS hover li tag inside the first ul select, Not select the first ul inside ul tag.
For example below the code.

```css
ul li:hover ul {display: block;}
ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> ( hover this li)
      <a href="#">Dropdown Link</a>
      <ul> ( Select this ul only )
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <ul> ( not select this ul )
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Please explain your question...!

Comment: hover the li tag, inside the first ul tag show but not show in nested ul tag, please check my code output you will understand

Comment: please provide better explanation and more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Answer is :**

```
<ul>
    <li class="link1"> ( hover this li)
      <a href="#" >Dropdown Link</a>
      <ul class="first-ul"> ( Select this ul only )
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="link2"><a href="#" >Link 3</a>
            <ul class="second-ul" > ( not select this ul )
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
.link1:hover .first-ul{display: block;}
.first-ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}

.link2:hover .second-ul{display: block;}

.second-ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
.second-ul, .first-ul { 
  background: #555; 
  display: none;
}
.secondUL{display:none}
```

[**View Code in Codepen:** Open](https://codepen.io/adyou2/pen/YzWpEog)

Comment: Thanks, I want this but li ul tag is the same class

Comment: if you are make it same classes , when you hover the first `<li>` tag, it will show the all `<UL>` Tag..

Comment: <li class="li-class"> tag same class and <ul class="ul-class"> tag all are same this class, I want that output

Comment: **you can do !**